# Catching A2HS dialog with Puppeteer-sharp

Tags: c#, progressive-web-apps, puppeteer-sharp

I want to do a headless PWA installation.
Using Puppeteer-sharp, I was able to click on the PWA Install button in the content to bring up the A2HS Dialog.
I thought I could handle this dialog with the "Dialog" class since the beforeinstallprompt object is displaying it with a prompt(), but I can't.

How do I catch the A2HS dialog?

[A2HS Dialog]
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/images/2018/06/a2hs-dialog-cropped.png

This is my code.
(It can catch window.prompt() and window.confirm().)

```
using (var browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(options))
using (var page = await browser.NewPageAsync())
{
    await page.GoToAsync("...");

    page.Dialog += new EventHandler<DialogEventArgs>(async (sender, args) => {
        // for test
        var alertMessage = args.Dialog.Message;
        Debug.WriteLine("*** {}", alertMessage);
        await args.Dialog.Dismiss();
    });

    var btnSelector = "#pwa_install_button";
    await page.WaitForSelectorAsync(btnSelector);
    await page.ClickAsync(btnSelector);
...
}
```

Comment: I attempted to do that at one point and also didn't find a solution.

Comment: Thanks, abraham!
It was not feasible in Puppeteer though I checked the specification and tried to do it by trial and error.
After all, I decided to use UI Automation.